# How to add 2 integers or Strings to a binary file sent by sockets? TCP

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, tcp

I am sending a binary file like a database or pdf file from client to sever TCP/IP by wifi.  The client is an Android tablet and the server is a windows 7 PC.

When sending the database or pdf, it is sent as a binary file.  How do I attach 2 short integers to this file?  For example a tablet serial number and a file size.

So the 2 integers and the file itself is sent all together.

The code I am using is shown here.

Server side code, for receiving file from client:

```
 File file = new File("C:/DBfiles/database.db);
 FileOutputStream fostr = new OutputStream(file);
 BufferedOutputsTream bostr = BufferedOutputStream(fostr);

 InutStream is = socket.getInputstream();

 byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

 while((( count = is.read())>0)&&(connected));
 bostr.write(buffer, 0, count);
```

Client side code, for sending a file to the server:

```
    File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/database.db");
    long length = file.length();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) length];

    FileInputStream fistr = new FileInputStream(file2);
    BufferedInputStream bistr = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    BufferedOutputStream bostr = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                int count;

                while ((count = bistr.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    bostr.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
```

Comment: Make a byte array with the 4 bytes (2 short) of data and write that buffer before the while() loop that copies the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the byte form of the string (byte for each character) and append them in buffer. I believe the integer you are saying are just 'string' for of integer. It is not meant for airthematic sum.